# Проблемы с кодировкой при парсинге некоторых сайтов, Golang

Tags: кодировка, парсер, golang, unicode

Доброго времени суток.
 Столкнулся с такой проблемой: некоторые сайты парсятся адекватно - текст из формочек достается в читабельной кодировке, а некоторые - нет.
Сначала грешил на UTF-8 на сайте, но ведь Go искаропки только с UTF-8 и работает по-дефолту
Получаю странику таким кодом:

```
func FetchHTML(url string) (string, bool){
    page := ""
    resp, HttpErr := http.Get(url)
    if HttpErr != nil {
        err := HTTPError{url, "", HttpErr.Error()}
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return "", false
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, IoErr := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if IoErr != nil {
        fmt.Println("IO error: ", IoErr.Error())
        return "", false
    }

    fmt.Println(body)
    page = string(body)
    fetched = true
    return page, true
}
```

Примеры:
Например, спарсим цитату из любимого всеми ithappens.
Передаю парсеру страничку по адресу http://ithappens.me/story/623
Получаем:

```
#623
КПД 100%
26 февраля 2009, 11:00

Приятель-программист поделился историей: написал для внутреннего пользования бенчмарк — в шестнадцати потоках перемножаются здоровенные матрицы. Все скомилировалось, запустилось и заработало, причем не просто быстро, а слишком быстро.
Матрицы перемножались мгновенно!
После разбора причин происходящего выяснилось, что тестовые матрицы представляли из себя массивы нулей. Умный интеловский компилято решил не загружать процессор перемножением и сложением нулей и оптимизировал код таким образом, чтобы сразу заполнить матрицы необходимого размера нулями.

Rating: 1866
Tags: чудеса техники, программы
```

Теперь пытаемся сделать то же самое, например, с http://bash.im/quote/435048 
Получаем:

```
#435048
2015-08-06 12:13
���: �� �������� ���� �������� ������, ��������� 15 ��� ������
���: ����� �������: ����, �� �� �����, �� ��� �� ������
���: �� ���, �� � ����. ��� � �� �����, � ����� ������� ����.
���: ���� �������, � ��� ��� ����� ��� ������ �����, �������� ������������ �� ������ ��������� ����� ������ ������
���: �� � � ������� �������, �������� - ���� �������������, ���������.     �������������. ������: ���� �����, 158, 161, 162 (�����, ������, ������), ��������� ��� ��� �� �������� - ���� ����� ������� �� ������ �� ����������. (�� ����� ���� - �����, ����� ����� �� ���� � ������ ������ ������). �, ������, ���������, �� ��� ��� � �� �������.
���: ��� ��������, ��������
���: � ��� �������, ��� �� ��� ������.
���: ��������� ���������. ��������� �� ���������, �� 4 �����, ������� � ���� - ������ ������. ���� ������� �� �����, ������������ ������ - ����� ��� � �������� �����. ���, ��, ����� ����, ����� ����... ���� ����, ��� ���� �������� � ���� �����, ��� ��� � � ����� ����� ���� ����� ����� ��. � ������: ��-�������, ���� �������� �������.
���: ����!!! � � ���� ��������, �� ������� ������, �� �������!!!
Rating:
```

Заметил, что в то время как байты текста с ithappens имеют значение 1??, байты текста bash.im переваливают в значениях за 200.
В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я рекомендую использовать пакет [golang.org/x/net/html/charset](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html/charset) и собственно его функцию [NewReader](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html/charset#NewReader).

Эта функция принимает собственно `io.Reader` и заголовок `Content-Type` если он есть. Функция анализирует `Content-Type` и первые 1024 байта тела и возвращает `io.Reader` в кодировке `UTF-8`, а так же ошибку, если она имеет место. Всё просто и круто.

Для примера:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/html/charset"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    url := "http://bash.im/quote/435048"
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("HTTP error:", err)
        return
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    // вот здесь и начинается самое интересное
    utf8, err := charset.NewReader(resp.Body, resp.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Encoding error:", err)
        return
    }
    // оп-па-ча, готово
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(utf8)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("IO error:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

Чем хорош этот способ - тем, что он универсален. Можно спокойно применять его для любого сайта. И нет нужды ковыряться в тегах вроде `<meta ...>`

[golang](/questions/tagged/golang) [кодировка](/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0) [парсер](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80)

Comment: Идеальный вариант, так действительно проще и понятнее

Answer (score 5):

Посмотрите на код того же bash.im'а:

```
<meta charset="windows-1251" />
```

Страница в кодировке Windows-1251. Чтобы перевести в UTF-8, пользуйтесь пакетами из [`golang.org/x/text`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text). Например:

```
dec := charmap.Windows1251.NewDecoder()
// Разные кодировки = разные длины символов.
newBody := make([]byte, len(body)*2)
n, _, err := dec.Transform(newBody, body, false)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
newBody = newBody[:n]
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас поищу.

Comment: Еще в заголовке ответа от сервера можно кодировку страницы увидеть: Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251

Comment: @Visman Ага. Это совсем меняет дело)

Comment: Все работает, всем спасибо)
Дергаю кодировку из хэдера, а потом, в зависимости от оной, декодирую

Comment: Можно воспользоваться этой библиотечкой https://github.com/softlandia/cpd она сможет определить кодировку ваших данных не опираясь на заголовок, а именно на данные.
Получив кодировку, делаем как в ответе Ainar-G.